# SSH connection to github. Error: github.com port 777: Connection timed out

Tags: git, github, ssh

I want to connect to github via ssh on a virtual hosting. When checking the connection with the command `ssh -T git@github.com`

When checking the connection using the command `ssh -T git@github.com`, an error occurs: `ssh: connect to host github.com port 777: Connection timed out`

But when executing the `ssh -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/github-key git@github.com` command, everything is successful:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi userName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

How do I execute git commands (for example, git pull)?

Contents of the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-key
Port 22
```

Contents of the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
Host *
        UseRoaming no
        ForwardAgent yes
        GSSAPIAuthentication yes
        Port 777
```

Comment: Well, that's weird. SSH should use port 22 by default. Could you provide the contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Comment: Added the output to the question

Comment: Does changing `777` to `22` in that file work?

Comment: Ehm i'm sorry, I meant `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. But it should be port 777 as well in that file I guess.

Comment: I can't edit the file: `-- INSERT -- W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file   `

Comment: Use `sudo vim`.

Comment: `sudo: command not found`